# Fan velocity at maximum

Tags: suspend, hp, fan

I have an HP 620 and I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 with Wubi. The problem is that after a suspension the fan runs at maximum. How can I fix that problem?

Comment: You should try clean Ubuntu installation, not Wubi.

Comment: See if HP has a bios update.

Answer (score 0):

Install [fancontrol [image: Install fancontrol]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/fancontrol)

Also update your BIOS like @psusi suggested.